# updated liquibase to 3.8.9 debug log started appearing by default

Tags: debugging, logging, upgrade, liquibase

As soon as I updated my liquibase jar to 3.8.9 from 3.5.3 I am seeing all the debug logs in my different project logs. How come debug mode is enabled by just upgrading the liquibase jar?
Liquibase 3.8.9 has 3 additional dependencies than tha last version 3.5.3 i.e. slf4-api, jaxb-api and logback-classic. Did anyone else faced similar issue if yes whats the solution to disable the debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there have been significant logging changes made since 3.5.3, you can update logging to your preference in your liquibase.properties file.  Here's a reference:
https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/loglevel.html
ex.

```
logLevel=off
```